# AJAX, send() seems to be redirected unintentionally

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I use AJAX to fill a list asynchronously. Right after loading web page, an AJAX request to fill list box is triggered. But when I send this request to server, an unintended web page (on which the list box exists) is returned instead of list data(JSON).

**[Components]**
**haveList.jsp** = There is list box. It includes `<script src="loadData.js">` tag.
**loadData.js** = It generates ajax request and send it to server. Right after loading `haveList.jsp`, `loadData.js` will be called. ( I'm just checking request get correct data from server using alert. )
**returnPage.java** = Servlet that forwards to `haveList.jsp`
**returnJsonData.java** = Servlet that returns json string that `loadData.js` asked for.
Each of these are shown below.

**[web.xml]**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ReturnPage</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>pkg.ReturnPage</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ReturnPage</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/openHaveList.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>DataManager</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>pkg.ReturnJsonData</servlet-class>    
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DataManager</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/requestListData.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**[Phenomenon]**
I sent "openHaveList.do" to server.
Page "haveList" returned.
Immediately an AJAX request to get JSON data occurred. (requestListData.do) (Refer to loadData.js below)
Using `alert()` I checked the content of `responseText` from server
I expected JSON data, but the HTML of `haveList.jsp` was there.

**[Clues]**
(1) When I got unintended html from server, browser's address bar showed `http://localhost/openHaveList.do`
( In other page, I click image. Then openHaveList.do occured. )
(2) When I captured request/response using ZAP (Zed Attack Proxy), I saw **2** requests occurred.
**The first** : requestListData.do ( Response : empty )
**The second** : openHaveList.do.  ( Response : html of haveList.jsp )
**Because of this, I suspect AJAX request is redirected unintentionally. ( requestListData.do --> openHaveList.do )**

**- Sources codes -**
**[haveList.jsp]**
Nothing special. There is list box

**[loadData.js]**

```
( function () {
var conn=null, addEvent=null, createXHR=null, loadNations = null, setAsyncLoad=null; 
addEvent = (function(window){
if(window.addEventListener){
   return function (element, eventName, callback, canCapture) {
     element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, canCapture);
 };
  } else if(window.attachEvent){
 return function (element, eventName, callback) {
 element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
 };
} else {
return function (element, eventName, callback) {
   element["on" + eventName] = callback;
  }
 }
 }(window));
 createXHR = function () {
 var xhrObj = null;
   try{
   xhrObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (exception){
    try{
   xhrObj = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
 } catch (innerException){
  xhrObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
 return xhrObj;
 }; 
  loadAsync = function () {
 var list = document.getElementById("list");   
  conn = createXHR();
  conn.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(conn.readyState == 4){
     if(conn.status == 200){
        alert(conn.responseText);  //--> Here it shows the html of haveList.jsp
     }
  }
};
conn.open('GET', 'requestListData.do');  
 conn.send();  
 };
 addEvent(window, 'load', function () { loadAsync(); } , false); 
} () );
```

**[returnPage.java]**

```
public class ReturnPage extends HttpServlet {
private static String page = "/haveList.jsp";
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);
dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);  
dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}
}
```

**[returnJsonData.java]**

```
public class ReturnJsonData extends HttpServlet {
private String command = null; 
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
strUri = request.getRequestURI();
command = strUri.substring(request.getContextPath().length());
try {
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
    response.getWriter().print( loadListData(request, command) );
} catch (Throwable e) {
  System.out.println("Failed to load list");
} 
}  
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
strUri = request.getRequestURI();
command = strUri.substring(request.getContextPath().length()); 
try {
   response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
   response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
   response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1L);
   response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
   response.getWriter().print( loadListData(request, command) );
 } catch (Throwable e) {
   System.out.println("Failed to load list");
 }  
 } 
private String loadListData(HttpServletRequest request, String command) throws Throwable 
{
String codeList = null;  
if("/requestListData.do".equals(command)){
   codeList = codeDao.select(conn);   
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!! ^^

**[Reason]**
Because of my **Filter**.

**[Detail]**
Actually, `haveList.jsp` is a **login** page. And I have a **filter** that checks if request was logged in. If not, that filter redirects request to **"haveList.jsp (login page)"**.
When ajax call to server **( requestListData.do )** was triggered, filter redirected request to login page because it was not logged in. Refer to following web.xml (Before).

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<filter-class>filter.Checker</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>escape</param-name>
<param-value>/Test/,/Test/gate.jsp,/Test/openHaveList.do</param-value>
</init-param>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>    
</filter-mapping>
```

**[Solution]**
I registered ajax call to server as exception. (escape parameter) In my **filter** servlet, I do not redirect such exception to login page **programmatically**. Refer to following web.xml (After).

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<filter-class>filter.Checker</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>escape</param-name>
<param-value>/Test/,/Test/gate.jsp,/Test/openHaveList.do,"/requestListData.do"</param-value>
</init-param>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Checker</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>    
</filter-mapping>
```

After this, I got JSON data from server. ^^